# Sending a tweet from an Android app to a handle and a particular hashtag

Tags: android, twitter

I have the handle and the hashtag and I just need to send a tweet from an Android app I'm developing. I have seen many different implementations (intents/OAuth etc) but all I need is to send a public tweet. Does a user have to be logged in for this? Do I need to user a library if all I need is to send a tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the user to authenticate your app to allow tweeting, so yes sign in is required to send a public tweet, as well as a library such as twitter4j. Check it out here 
[twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#introduction)
Also, you have to sign your application on twitter to receive a consumer key and consumer secret to add to your application's twitter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but yes, the user needs to be logged in.

You cannot post a tweet with no account.